# How to sort month in calendar order using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT Value,month,Year FROM `rainfall_past` WHERE Year = '2006' and District= 'Colombo'
```

this will return the following results

```
Value   month       Year    
103.4   April       2006    
270.6   August      2006    
51.9    December    2006    
156.9   February    2006    
126.9   January     2006    
96.8    July        2006    
183.1   June        2006    
266.6   March       2006    
193.1   May         2006    
524.7   November    2006    
619.9   October     2006    
129     September   2006
```

the problem is that as u can see the months are not in the calendar order. how can query this in calendar months order. i don't want to add additional column to the table or write a script in my source code to sort this. is there any way i can do this in my query only. thanks guys for ur support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `month` is a text field. If this is the case, then you can use [**`FIELD`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT Value, month, Year 
FROM `rainfall_past` 
WHERE Year = '2006' and District= 'Colombo' 
ORDER BY Year,
         FIELD(month, 'January', 'February', ..., 'December')
```

If, on the other hand, `month` is deduced from a datetime field, you can use `MONTH(date)`.